# Sweet potato planting distance

Tags: planting, sweet-potato

I'm planning 30 cm apart in rows (~12 inches) and 0.5m rows distance (~19.5 inches). But, isn't it too densely? I'm even considering 30/30 cm (30 cm rows distance as well).

Does planting density actually affect to crop amount/tubers size? Vines are usually very long, but they will be always much longer than distance between plants, so 30 cm or even 50 cm should not make any difference. From other side, distance like 30 cm should be enough to give a room for tubers in ground, what do you think?

When searching for info, I got various recommendations, so I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are several varieties. Each will want a different density. You want them far enough apart that they don't shade each other or compete underground. Your source of seeds should be able to tell you about that. Slightly extra space is probably less harmful than too little space.

Some plants need to flower and be fertilized before they will produce. In that case, you want them to be in an arrangement that bees will find multiple plants while loaded with pollen. So at least two rows, preferably more.

Rows should allow you room to get down between them to weed or water as required. You can put two rows close together, then a larger gap for access.

Some species can be planted extra thick, then thinned out as they start to produce. I do that with carrots. Get a bunch of baby carrots early on, then larger ones later. Maybe it does not apply to sweet potato.

Comment: Your guide is general rules. I don't think it applies to sweet potato, no way vines will be shaded for example + flowering does not matter